# NoSuchFileException while reading a file

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file, but I get a `NoSuchFileException`. I know my code work, because it works in another program I have created, but it doesn't work now. Yes the directory is correct and there is a text file in the *src* folder. Please could someone tell me how to fix this.

```
String[] words = new String[5];

Path file = Paths.get("H:\\Varsity work\\Java Programming\\Programs\\HangMan\\build\\classes\\HangMan.txt");
InputStream  input = null;
try {
    input = Files.newInputStream(file);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    String s = null;

    while((s=reader.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    input.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I wonder what you expect. `NoSuchFileException` is pretty clear and we don't know how your directory structure looks like. The file is not where you think it is, or Java has no permission to access it. There is nothing else to say about that.

Comment: @Tom would you say its a Problem with the program i am using because i have said before, my other program works but then not this one?

Comment: No, what I say is that the path `"H:\\Varsity work\\Java Programming\\Programs\\HangMan\\build\\classes\\HangMan.txt"` is not correct (or the permission aren't set correctly). It has nothing to do with your other program. It all depends on the path and where the file ***really*** is.

Comment: If it's a permission issue, it's more likely to be an `AccessDeniedException`.  This exception clearly means the file is not there.  End of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using '/' instead of '\' , so no need to escape any chars and path string used as is.

Comment: it would be helpful to add more info, at what line the exception occurs ? if you copy and paste the path in the explorer does it work ? is the "H:\" driver accessible from the program ?

Comment: This is the error it gives, java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: H:\Varsity work\Java Programming\Programs\HangMan\build\classes\HangMan.txt

Comment: sorry, but this does not answer any of the 3 question !

Comment: It does not give any line at which the exceception occurs, Yes it does work in the path explorer and it is accesible. @nabeel